# What is the most efficient way to loop through dataframes with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, for-loop

I want to perform my own complex operations on financial data in dataframes in a sequential manner.

For example I am using the following MSFT CSV file taken from [Yahoo Finance](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=MSFT):

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
2011-10-19,27.37,27.47,27.01,27.13,42880000,27.13
2011-10-18,26.94,27.40,26.80,27.31,52487900,27.31
2011-10-17,27.11,27.42,26.85,26.98,39433400,26.98
2011-10-14,27.31,27.50,27.02,27.27,50947700,27.27

....
```

I then do the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pandas import *

df = read_csv('table.csv')

for i, row in enumerate(df.values):
    date = df.index[i]
    open, high, low, close, adjclose = row
    #now perform analysis on open/close based on date, etc..
```

Is that the most efficient way? Given the focus on speed in pandas, I would assume there must be some special function to iterate through the  values in a manner that one also retrieves the index (possibly through a generator to be memory efficient)? `df.iteritems` unfortunately only iterates column by column.

Comment: have you tried writing a function and passing it to `df.apply()`?

Comment: If you want memory efficieny you should consider using vectorized operations (using matrices and vectors). But I don't know pandas, so I can't tell you, whether such operations are possible there.

Comment: Citing `unutbu`, NumPy seems to support vectorized operations (`The key to speed with NumPy arrays is to perform your operations on the whole array at once`).

Comment: The question was specific to sequential iteration, as is very common in finance, where vectorization is not often possible. And the accepted answer by Nick Crawford answers that and additionally cautions to use vectorization where possible.

Comment: I don't normally ask the asker to move their accepted vote, but this is a rare case where I will. Consider moving it to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77539762/4561887). The currently-accepted answer recommends `iterrows()`, which is **600x slower** than the fastest technique, or `itertuples()`, which is **15x** slower. So, consider moving the accepted answer to my answer, where I present the **1x** and other techniques, and meticulously speed test them all.

Comment: See also: [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16476924/4561887). I have [speed tested 13+ techniques there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77270285/4561887).

Answer (score 425, accepted):

The newest versions of pandas now include a built-in function for iterating over rows.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():

    # do some logic here
```

Or, if you want it faster use `itertuples()`

But, unutbu's suggestion to use numpy functions to avoid iterating over rows will produce the fastest code.

Comment: Note that `iterrows` is very slow (it converts every row to a series, potentially messing with your data types). When you need an iterator, better to use `itertuples`

Comment: BTW itertuples returns named tuples ( https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) so you can access each column by name with row.high or getattr(row,'high')

Comment: Be aware, according to current [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html): "You should **never modify** something you are iterating over. This is not guaranteed to work in all cases. Depending on the data types, the iterator returns a copy and not a view, and writing to it will have no effect."

Comment: Hey, how to use unutbu's solution if I want to iterate efficiently over a Pandas Series ?

Comment: @joris. I can't agree you more, `itertuples` is approximately 100 times fater than `iterrows`.

Comment: fjsj: since the question asked about 'looping' and 'efficiency' I provided a response that answered both parts of the question. No one should loop over a dataframe unless they absolutely have to.

Comment: itertuples(name=None) is even faster because it will yield normal tuples instead of namedtuples. See this interesting article : https://medium.com/swlh/why-pandas-itertuples-is-faster-than-iterrows-and-how-to-make-it-even-faster-bc50c0edd30d

Comment: [I speed tested 13 techniques in my answer I just added here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77539762/4561887). `iterrows()` is **~600x slower** than the fastest technique, which is _pure vectorization_, and _list comprehension_ is only **~10x slower** than pure vectorization, while still being easy to maintain. So...if you're looking for "the most efficient way to loop through dataframes with Pandas", absolutely avoid `iterrows()`.

Answer (score 169):

Pandas is based on NumPy arrays.
The key to speed with NumPy arrays is to perform your operations on the whole array at once, never row-by-row or item-by-item.

For example, if `close` is a 1-d array, and you want the day-over-day percent change,

```
pct_change = close[1:]/close[:-1]
```

This computes the entire array of percent changes as one statement, instead of

```
pct_change = []
for row in close:
    pct_change.append(...)
```

So try to avoid the Python loop `for i, row in enumerate(...)` entirely, and
think about how to perform your calculations with operations on the entire array (or dataframe) as a whole, rather than row-by-row.

Comment: I agree that this is the best way and that is what I usually do for simple operations. However, in this case, this is not possible, since the resulting operations can get very complex. Specifically I am trying to backtest trading strategies.

E.g. if the price is at a new low over a 30d period, then we might want to buy the stock and get out whenever a certain condition is met and this needs to be simulated in-place. This simple example could still be done by vectorization, however, the more complex a trading-strategy gets, the less possible it becomes to use vectorization.

Comment: You'll have to explain in more detail the exact calculation you are trying to perform. It helps to write the code any way you can first, then profile and optimize it.

Comment: By the way, for some calculations (especially those that can not be expressed as operations on whole arrays) code using Python lists can be faster than equivalent code using numpy arrays.

Comment: I agree vectorization is the right solution where possible-- sometimes an iterative algorithm is the only way though.

Comment: late comment, but i have found that trying to do full calculation for a column is sometimes difficult to write and debug.   Consider intermediary calculation columns,  makes it easier to debug and understand the calculations.   have found that even the most complex logic can be implemented like this, while still avoiding looping.

Comment: @Joop agreed, late comment on your comment. I once had a project where I put all or the meantime steps of whatever calculation I needed in columns. The table became large, > 1000 columns, since I had to repeat the calculations even for time series points of the last x years. But it was worth it, the table could be always traced back to where everything came from. You can make one table for each bigger step. Yet, I appended the changed time series columns always to the right of the table, with a dummy column in between, which mad less work with table relations. You will need good prefixes.

Answer (score 138):

Like what has been mentioned before, pandas object is most efficient when process the whole array at once. However for those who really need to loop through a pandas DataFrame to perform something, like me, I found at least three ways to do it. I have done a short test to see which one of the three is the least time consuming.

```
t = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(0, 10000), 'b': range(10000, 20000)})
B = []
C = []
A = time.time()
for i,r in t.iterrows():
    C.append((r['a'], r['b']))
B.append(time.time()-A)

C = []
A = time.time()
for ir in t.itertuples():
    C.append((ir[1], ir[2]))    
B.append(time.time()-A)

C = []
A = time.time()
for r in zip(t['a'], t['b']):
    C.append((r[0], r[1]))
B.append(time.time()-A)

print B
```

Result:

```
[0.5639059543609619, 0.017839908599853516, 0.005645036697387695]
```

This is probably not the best way to measure the time consumption but it's quick for me.

Here are some pros and cons IMHO:

- .iterrows(): return index and row items in separate variables, but significantly slower
- .itertuples(): faster than .iterrows(), but return index together with row items, ir[0] is the index
- zip: quickest, but no access to index of the row

### EDIT 2020/11/10

For what it is worth, here is an updated benchmark with some other alternatives (perf with MacBookPro 2,4 GHz Intel Core i9 8 cores 32 Go 2667 MHz DDR4)

```py
import sys
import tqdm
import time
import pandas as pd

B = []
t = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(0, 10000), 'b': range(10000, 20000)})
for _ in tqdm.tqdm(range(10)):
    C = []
    A = time.time()
    for i,r in t.iterrows():
        C.append((r['a'], r['b']))
    B.append({"method": "iterrows", "time": time.time()-A})

    C = []
    A = time.time()
    for ir in t.itertuples():
        C.append((ir[1], ir[2]))
    B.append({"method": "itertuples", "time": time.time()-A})

    C = []
    A = time.time()
    for r in zip(t['a'], t['b']):
        C.append((r[0], r[1]))
    B.append({"method": "zip", "time": time.time()-A})

    C = []
    A = time.time()
    for r in zip(*t.to_dict("list").values()):
        C.append((r[0], r[1]))
    B.append({"method": "zip + to_dict('list')", "time": time.time()-A})

    C = []
    A = time.time()
    for r in t.to_dict("records"):
        C.append((r["a"], r["b"]))
    B.append({"method": "to_dict('records')", "time": time.time()-A})

    A = time.time()
    t.agg(tuple, axis=1).tolist()
    B.append({"method": "agg", "time": time.time()-A})

    A = time.time()
    t.apply(tuple, axis=1).tolist()
    B.append({"method": "apply", "time": time.time()-A})

print(f'Python {sys.version} on {sys.platform}')
print(f"Pandas version {pd.__version__}")
print(
    pd.DataFrame(B).groupby("method").agg(["mean", "std"]).xs("time", axis=1).sort_values("mean")
)

## Output

Python 3.7.9 (default, Oct 13 2020, 10:58:24) 
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.2)] on darwin
Pandas version 1.1.4
                           mean       std
method                                   
zip + to_dict('list')  0.002353  0.000168
zip                    0.003381  0.000250
itertuples             0.007659  0.000728
to_dict('records')     0.025838  0.001458
agg                    0.066391  0.007044
apply                  0.067753  0.006997
iterrows               0.647215  0.019600
```

Comment: NB in Python 3 `zip()` returns an iterator, so use `list(zip())`

Comment: Could you not use `t.index` to loop through the index?

Comment: This is great; thanks Richard. It is still relevant with Python 3.7+. From 286 seconds with iterrows to 3.62 with zip. Thanks

Comment: I have re-run this benchmark with pandas.__version__ == 1.1.4, Python 3.7.9 and brand new MacBookPro 2,4 GHz Intel Core i9 8 cores 32 Go 2667 MHz DDR4, and the results is even worst for `iterrows()`: `[0.6970570087432861, 0.008062124252319336, 0.0036787986755371094]`

Comment: @ClementWalter, nice!

Comment: To be noted that zip + to_dict method much less memory efficient than itertuples.

Comment: Glad to see someone else speed testing. Here are my 13+ techniques speed tested and plotted [here (summary answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77539762/4561887), [here (full answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77270285/4561887), and on my personal website [here (full writeup)](https://gabrielstaples.com/python_iterate_over_pandas_dataframe/#gsc.tab=0). The results are quite dramatic.

Answer (score 75):

You can loop through the rows by transposing and then calling iteritems:

```
for date, row in df.T.iteritems():
   # do some logic here
```

I am not certain about efficiency in that case. To get the best possible performance in an iterative algorithm, you might want to explore writing it in [Cython](http://cython.org), so you could do something like:

```
def my_algo(ndarray[object] dates, ndarray[float64_t] open,
            ndarray[float64_t] low, ndarray[float64_t] high,
            ndarray[float64_t] close, ndarray[float64_t] volume):
    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t i, n
        float64_t foo
    n = len(dates)

    for i from 0 <= i < n:
        foo = close[i] - open[i] # will be extremely fast
```

I would recommend writing the algorithm in pure Python first, make sure it works and see how fast it is-- if it's not fast enough, convert things to Cython like this with minimal work to get something that's about as fast as hand-coded C/C++.

Comment: I also recommend Cython; I was working on a similar problem for building my backtesting engine, and I got a 1,000x speedup. I then combined that with the multiprocessing library, which is a very nice combination.

Comment: This answer needs updating to include the new `df.iterrows()` as per @NickCrawford's answer.

Comment: `df.T.iteritems()` is a great solution rather than using `df.iterrows()` if you want to iterate over a specific column +1

Comment: Gives error:   `def my_algo(ndarray[object] dates, ndarray[float64_t] opn,
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Answer (score 62):

You have three options:

By [index](https://www.neural-networks.io/en/python/dataframes.php#iterate-over-rows-by-index) (simplest):

```
>>> for index in df.index:
...     print ("df[" + str(index) + "]['B']=" + str(df['B'][index]))
```

With [iterrows](https://www.neural-networks.io/en/python/dataframes.php#iterate-over-rows-with-iterrows) (most used):

```
>>> for index, row in df.iterrows():
...     print ("df[" + str(index) + "]['B']=" + str(row['B']))
```

With [itertuples](https://www.neural-networks.io/en/python/dataframes.php#iterate-over-rows-with-itertuples) (fastest):

```
>>> for row in df.itertuples():
...     print ("df[" + str(row.Index) + "]['B']=" + str(row.B))
```

Three options display something like:

```
df[0]['B']=125
df[1]['B']=415
df[2]['B']=23
df[3]['B']=456
df[4]['B']=189
df[5]['B']=456
df[6]['B']=12
```

Source: [alphons.io](https://alphons.io/2101/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-loop-through-dataframes-with-pandas/)

Comment: There is something even three times as fast as the itertuples, see [the answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34311080/11154841). Which was answered three years before. Still, just using the index was something new here (this should not be used, just the idea is plain and simple).

Answer (score 26):

I checked out `iterrows` after noticing [Nick Crawford's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/475872/nick-crawford) answer, but found that it yields (index, Series) tuples. Not sure which would work best for you, but I ended up using the `itertuples` method for my problem, which yields (index, row_value1...) tuples.

There's also `iterkv`, which iterates through (column, series) tuples.

Comment: you can do something like dict(row) to make a set out of the row with searchable columns

Comment: I also found itertuples to be much faster (10x) in my use case as Series objects are not being created.

Comment: FYI: `iterkv` deprecated since 0.13.1

Comment: `iterrows(): Iterate over the rows of a DataFrame as (index, Series) pairs....
itertuples(): Iterate over the rows of a DataFrame as tuples of the values. This is a lot faster as iterrows(), and is in most cases preferable to use to iterate over the values of a DataFrame.`

Answer (score 21):

Just as a small addition, you can also do an apply if you have a complex function that you apply to a single column:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

```
df[b] = df[a].apply(lambda col: do stuff with col here)
```

Comment: probably x is a confusing name for the column name and the row variable, though I agree apply is easiest way to do it :)

Comment: just to add, `apply` can also be applied to multiple columns:
`df['c'] = df[['a','b']].apply(lambda x: do stuff with x[0] and x[1] here, axis=1)`

Comment: Can apply take in a function defined elsewhere in code? this is  so that we can introduce a more complicated function

Comment: Yes, the lambda function can use any kind of user defined function. Mind you: if you have a large dataframe, you might want to revert to cython instead (Python has a bit of overhead when it comes to calling functions)

Comment: I renamed `x` -> `col`. Better name

Comment: `DataFrame.apply` is not limited to one column; try `df.apply(lambda x: print(x.a + x,b), axis = 1)`

Comment: @user308827 The function you give to apply() doesn't have to be a lambda, can be any callable - so a function defined elsewhere, or a class that defines __call__, etc

Answer (score 15):

As [@joris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/653364/joris) pointed out, `iterrows` is much slower than `itertuples` and `itertuples` is approximately 100 times faster than `iterrows`, and I tested the speed of both methods in a DataFrame with 5 million records the result is for `iterrows`, it is 1200it/s, and  `itertuples` is 120000it/s.

If you use `itertuples`, note that every element in the for loop is a namedtuple, so to get the value in each column, you can refer to the following example code

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [0.1, 0.2]},
                      index=['a', 'b'])
>>> df
   col1  col2
a     1   0.1
b     2   0.2
>>> for row in df.itertuples():
...     print(row.col1, row.col2)
...
1, 0.1
2, 0.2
```

Answer (score 12):

For sure, the fastest way to iterate over a dataframe is to access the underlying numpy ndarray either via `df.values` (as you do) or by accessing each column separately `df.column_name.values`. Since you want to have access to the index too, you can use `df.index.values` for that.

```
index = df.index.values
column_of_interest1 = df.column_name1.values
...
column_of_interestk = df.column_namek.values

for i in range(df.shape[0]):
   index_value = index[i]
   ...
   column_value_k = column_of_interest_k[i]
```

Not pythonic? Sure. But fast.

If you want to squeeze more juice out of the loop you will want to look into [cython](http://cython.org/). Cython will let you gain huge speedups (think 10x-100x). For maximum performance check [memory views for cython](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html).

Answer (score 5):

Another suggestion would be to combine groupby with vectorized calculations if subsets of the rows shared characteristics which allowed you to do so.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the most simple and efficient way to loop through DataFrames is using numpy and numba.  In that case, looping can be approximately as fast as vectorized operations in many cases.  If numba is not an option, plain numpy is likely to be the next best option.  As has been noted many times, your default should be vectorization, but this answer merely considers efficient looping, given the decision to loop, for whatever reason.

For a test case, let's use the example from @DSM's answer of calculating a percentage change.  This is a very simple situation and as a practical matter you would not write a loop to calculate it, but as such it provides a reasonable baseline for timing vectorized approaches vs loops.

Let's set up the 4 approaches with a small DataFrame, and we'll time them on a larger dataset below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

df = pd.DataFrame( { 'close':[100,105,95,105] } )

pandas_vectorized = df.close.pct_change()[1:]

x = df.close.to_numpy()
numpy_vectorized = ( x[1:] - x[:-1] ) / x[:-1]
        
def test_numpy(x):
    pct_chng = np.zeros(len(x))
    for i in range(1,len(x)):
        pct_chng[i] = ( x[i] - x[i-1] ) / x[i-1]
    return pct_chng

numpy_loop = test_numpy(df.close.to_numpy())[1:]

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def test_numba(x):
    pct_chng = np.zeros(len(x))
    for i in range(1,len(x)):
        pct_chng[i] = ( x[i] - x[i-1] ) / x[i-1]
    return pct_chng
    
numba_loop = test_numba(df.close.to_numpy())[1:]
```

And here are the timings on a DataFrame with 100,000 rows (timings performed with Jupyter's `%timeit` function, collapsed to a summary table for readability):

```
pandas/vectorized   1,130 micro-seconds
numpy/vectorized      382 micro-seconds
numpy/looped       72,800 micro-seconds
numba/looped          455 micro-seconds
```

Summary:  for simple cases, like this one, you would go with (vectorized) pandas for simplicity and readability, and (vectorized) numpy for speed.  If you really need to use a loop, do it in numpy.  If numba is available, combine it with numpy for additional speed.  In this case, numpy + numba is almost as fast as vectorized numpy code.

Other details:

- Not shown are various options like iterrows, itertuples, etc. which are orders of magnitude slower and really should never be used.
- The timings here are fairly typical: numpy is faster than pandas and vectorized is faster than loops, but adding numba to numpy will often speed numpy up dramatically.
- Everything except the pandas option requires converting the DataFrame column to a numpy array.  That conversion is included in the timings.
- The time to define/compile the numpy/numba functions was not included in the timings, but would generally be a negligible component of the timing for any large dataframe.

Answer (score 4):

look at last one

```
t = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(0, 10000), 'b': range(10000, 20000)})
B = []
C = []
A = time.time()
for i,r in t.iterrows():
    C.append((r['a'], r['b']))
B.append(round(time.time()-A,5))

C = []
A = time.time()
for ir in t.itertuples():
    C.append((ir[1], ir[2]))    
B.append(round(time.time()-A,5))

C = []
A = time.time()
for r in zip(t['a'], t['b']):
    C.append((r[0], r[1]))
B.append(round(time.time()-A,5))

C = []
A = time.time()
for r in range(len(t)):
    C.append((t.loc[r, 'a'], t.loc[r, 'b']))
B.append(round(time.time()-A,5))

C = []
A = time.time()
[C.append((x,y)) for x,y in zip(t['a'], t['b'])]
B.append(round(time.time()-A,5))
B

0.46424
0.00505
0.00245
0.09879
0.00209
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is that the most efficient way? Given the focus on speed in pandas, I would assume there must be some special function to iterate through the values...

There absolutely is a most-efficient way: **vectorization**. After that comes **list comprehension**, followed by **`itertuples()`**. Stay away from `iterrows()`. It's pretty horrible, coming in much slower than a raw for loop with regular `df["A"][i]`-type indexing, even.

I present 13 ways in great detail here, speed testing them all, and showing all of the code: [How to iterate over Pandas `DataFrame`s [with and without] iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77270285/4561887).

I spend several weeks writing that answer. Here are the results:

[image]

##### Key takeaways::

1. If your goal is code that is **easy to read, write, and maintain,** while still being really fast, use **list comprehension**. It is only **~10x slower** than pure vectorization.
2. If your goal is code that is **as fast as possible**, use **pure vectorization**. It is harder to read and write when you have complicated equations such as `if` statements in your formula you are calculating for each row, however.

Functions like `iterrows()` are *horribly slow*, at **~600x slower** than pure vectorization.

To prove that all 13 techniques I speed tested are possible even in complicated formulas, I chose this non-trivial formula to calculate via all of the techniques, where `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` are columns, and the `i` subscripts are rows (ex: `i-2` is 2 rows up, `i-1` is the previous row, `i` is the current row, `i+1` is the next row, etc.):

[image]

For a ton more detail, and the code for all 13 techniques, refer to my main answer: [How to iterate over Pandas `DataFrame`s without iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77270285/4561887).