# Faster processing of Dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to process very large files (10,000+ observsstions) where zip codes are not easily formatted.  I need to convert them all to just the first 5 digits, and here is my current code:

```
def makezip(frame, zipcol):
    i = 0
    while i < len(frame):
        frame[zipcol][i] = frame[zipcol][i][:5]
        i += 1
    return frame
```

frame is the dataframe, and zipcol is the name of the column containing the zip codes. Although this works, it takes a very long time to process.  Is there a quicker way?

Comment: You need to avoid for-loops and use the 'apply' methods. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837722/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-loop-through-dataframes-with-pandas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `.str` accessor on string columns to access some specific string methods. And on this, you can also slice:

```
frame[zipcol] = frame[zipcol].str[:5]
```

---

Based on a small example, this is around 50 times faster as looping over the rows:

```
In [29]: s = pd.Series(['testtest']*10000)

In [30]: %timeit s.str[:5]
100 loops, best of 3: 3.06 ms per loop

In [31]: %timeit str_loop(s)
10 loops, best of 3: 164 ms per loop
```

whith

```
In [27]: def str_loop(s):
   .....:     for i in range(len(s)):
   .....:         s[i] = s[i][:5]
   .....:
```