# How can I build a DataFrame Incrementally

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to build a master DataFrame over time. Lets say its imported from a csv file and looks something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']).rename_axis='Date'
```

At some point in time I will have a DataFrame like this, that I will append to df.

```
dfb = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2']).rename_axis('Date')
```

At a later point in time I will have another DataFrame, call it dfe, containing the remaiming col3 and col4.

```
dfe = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col3', 'col4']).rename_axis('Date')
```

How do I add dfe to df such that it fills in on the same row and does not generate additional columns. I tried:

```
df = pd.concat([df, dfe], axis=1)
```

but new columns are generated. I think this is because the previous append step put `NaN` values in `col3` and `col4`.

UPDATE: I asked this in a somewhat different way and recieved great answers. See the post here.

[How to replace missing data in DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58780163/how-to-replace-missing-data-in-dataframe)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504033/dataframe-append-a-row)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the `df.merge(dfe)` [function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).
This will merge your columns according to the date index.
Bare in mind that, in case of conflicts you can decide which value will "win".