# How can I optimize this X-Ray selection cycle?

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have the following code

```
facts = []
with tqdm(total=6022484) as pbar:
for lat in dp.lat:
    for lon in dp.lon:
        for time in dp.time:
            fact = {\
                    'datetime':datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(time.values)/1000000000.),\
                    'loc':[float(lon.values),float(lat.values)],\
                    'temp':celsius(dp.sel(lat=lat.values,lon=lon.values,time=time.values).t2m.values),\
                    'rh':round(dp.sel(lat=lat.values,lon=lon.values,time=time.values).rh.values,1),\
                    'rain':round(dp.sel(lat=lat.values,lon=lon.values,time=time.values).rain.values,1)
                   }
            facts.append(fact)
            pbar.update()
```

making aprox. 100 iteration per second. Is it possible to do best?

Answer (score 1):

Generally this approach is going to be *extremely* slow. Instead of iterating through these in python, you should use the standard functions which operate across the values in a vectorized way.

For example, `dp.lat = dp.lat.astype('float')`, or `dp.rain = np.round(dp.rain, 0)`.

This is a similar discussion: [What is the most efficient way to loop through dataframes with pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837722/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-loop-through-dataframes-with-pandas)

Comment: I found out that converting to Dataframe is quite fast. The problem now is to convert the dataframe to dict before inserting in Mongo Collection. I have aprox 6 million rows

Comment: `DataFrame.to_dict()`?

Comment: But it's also going to be slow converting from a DataFrame to a dict - you haven't materially helped the speed by putting in a DataFrame quickly