# Performance of looping with pandas

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I originally asked [a question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/10493/convert-some-observations-into-variables) in Data Science community:

> I have a table formatted like the following table:
>
> ```
> Feature amount    ID  
> Feat1    2        1   
> Feat2    0        1   
> Feat3    0        1   
> Feat4    1        1   
> Feat2    2        2   
> Feat4    0        2   
> Feat3    0        2   
> Feat6    1        2
> ```
>
> Let's say I have 200 different IDs. I want to convert all different
>   features into variables and amount into observations, so I combine
>   rows with same ID into one row. For example,
>
> ```
> Feat1 Feat2 Feat3 Feat4 Feat5 Feat6 ID 
>   2     0     0     1    NA    NA   1    
>  NA     2     0     0    NA    1    2
> ```
>
> Is there a good way to do it either in Python (pandas) or R?

And this is the answer I got:

> ```
> newdata = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'Location', 'Feat1', 'Feat2', 'Feat3', 'Feat4', 'Feat5', 'Feat6'])
> grouped = data.groupby(['ID', 'Location'])
>
> for index, (group_name, d) in enumerate(grouped):
>     newdata.loc[index, 'ID'] = group_name[0]
>     newdata.loc[index, 'Location'] = group_name[1]
>     for feature, amount in zip(d['Feature'], d['amount']):
>         newdata.loc[index, feature] = amount
> ```

After more Google search, I found the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837722/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-loop-through-dataframes-with-pandas) says:

> So try to avoid the Python `loop for i, row in enumerate(...)` entirely

I am wondering, regarding to my original question, is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you're after.

```
>>> df.pivot_table(values='amount', index='ID', columns='Feature')
Feature  Feat1  Feat2  Feat3  Feat4  Feat6
ID                                        
1            2      0      0      1    NaN
2          NaN      2      0      0      1
```

Depending on your data and needs, there are variations. For example:

```
>>> df.pivot_table(values='amount', index='ID', columns='Feature', 
                   aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0)
Feature  Feat1  Feat2  Feat3  Feat4  Feat6
ID                                        
1            2      0      0      1      0
2            0      2      0      0      1
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I deleted the location column, it is not a factor to this question.