# Python Pandas, creating new series from calculations on existing series

Tags: python, pandas

I'm fairly new to Python and Pandas, I'm trying to pull some statistics from a Series.  **I want to calculate the difference between the last row and the first row**, and put that in a new Series.

My first series looks similar to this:

```
#    Symbol(1)  Symbol(2)  Symbol(3)
Mon  5          10         15
Tue  6          9          12
Wed  3          11         15
```

I would like to know how to easily create this resultant Series:

```
#    Symbol(1)  Symbol(2)  Symbol(3)
Diff -2         1          0
```

This is the latest iteration of the code I tried:

```
diffy = pd.concat([inputs.head(1),inputs.tail(1)])
diffy.dropna(axis='columns', inplace='true')

a = pd.Series(index=diffy.index)
for c in diffy.columns:
    a.append(pd.Series(data=[diffy[c][1]-diffy[c][0]], index=c))
```

However, I get a `TypeError` on the last line, where I try to append the information.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7837947/1158313) seems to be a very similar issue, but the accepted answer doesn't quite provide the full details.

Comment: not very clear what you try to compute

Comment: *where* do you get a TypeError? Show the full traceback please.

Comment: @OphirYoktan, I clarified the question a little.

Comment: @SiHa, I clarified the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
diffy = inputs.iloc[-1, :] - inputs.iloc[0, :] # pandas Series
```

and you can do

```
inputs = inputs.append(diffy, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Well I knew it was something easy.  I had tried `inputs.iloc[1:] - inputs.iloc[:1]` based on the referenced question/answer so I was close!