# replace certain number in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, replace, dataframe

I am pretty new to Python programming and have a question about replacing certain conditional number in a DataFrame. 
for example, I have a dateframe with 5 days of data in each column, day1, day2, day3, day4 and day5. For each day, I have 5 data points with some of them larger than 5 for each day. Now I want to set the data which is larger than 5 to 1. 
So how can I do that? Loop into each column and find specific element then change it, or there is other faster way to do it?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

To do this without looping (which is usually faster) you can do:

```
df[df > 5] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This will iterate over the data in each column and change high values to 1. Iterating by rows instead of columns is an option with `iterrows` as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11617194/6085135), but it's generally slower.

```
import pandas as pd


data = {'day1' : pd.Series([1, 2, 3]),
        'day2' : pd.Series([1, 4, 6]),
        'day3' : pd.Series([5, 4, 3]),
        'day4' : pd.Series([2, 4, 6]),
        'day5' : pd.Series([7, 3, 2])}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = [x if x <= 5 else 1 for x in df[col]]
```

[image]