# How to optimize code that iterates on a big dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, dataframe

I have a big pandas dataframe. It has thousands of columns and over a million rows. I want to calculate the difference between the max value and the min value row-wise. Keep in mind that there are many NaN values and some rows are all NaN values (but I still want to keep them!).

I wrote the following code. It works but it's time consuming:

```
totTime = []
for index, row in date.iterrows():
    myRow = row.dropna()
    if len(myRow):
        tt = max(myRow) - min(myRow)
    else:
        tt = None
    totTime.append(tt)
```

Is there any way to optimize it? I tried with the following code but I get an error when it encounters all NaN rows:

```
tt = lambda x: max(x.dropna()) - min(x.dropna())
totTime = date.apply(tt, axis=1)
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: IIUC you can just do `date.max(axis=1) - data.min(axis=1)`

Comment: You should avoid using loops and `apply` and search for a vectorised method like I suggested, most pandas ops will handle `NaN` gracefully you then need to filter out either before or after the operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is usually a bad idea to use a `python` `for` loop to iterate over a large `pandas.DataFrame` or a `numpy.ndarray`. You should rather use the available build in functions on them as they are optimized and in many cases actually not written in python but in a compiled language. In your case you should use the methods [pandas.DataFrame.max](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) and [pandas.DataFrame.min](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.min.html) that both give you an option `skipna` to skip `nan` values in your `DataFrame` without the need to actually drop them manually. Furthermore, you can choose a `axis` to minimize along. So you can specifiy `axis=1` to get the minimum along columns.

This will add up to something similar as what @EdChum just mentioned in the comments:

```
data.max(axis=1, skipna=True) - data.min(axis=1, skipna=True)
```

Comment: `skipna` is default `True` so it's unnecessary: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html

Comment: Oh good to know, thanks. I usually prefer explicit over implicit and will keep it thus.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem about iterating. 2 points:

1. Why don't you replace NaN values with 0? You can do it with this `df.replace(['inf','nan'],[0,0])`. It replaces inf and nan values.
2. Take a look at this [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837722/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-loop-through-dataframes-with-pandas/7837947#7837947). Maybe you can understand, I have a similar question about how to optimize the loop to calculate de difference between actual row with the previous one.

Comment: Hi Juliana. I do not replace NaN values with 0 because NaN in my case means means missing and 0 is a possible measurement. If I were to replace NaN with 0, my data would no longer represent my case. I also agree with the post you shared. Avoiding for loops is the key.