# list comprehension in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

I'm giving a toy example but it will help me understand what's going on for something else I'm trying to do. Let's say I want a new column in a dataframe 'optimal_fruit' that is apples * orange - bananas.

I can do something like this to get it.

```
df2['optimal_fruit'] = df2['apples'] * df2['oranges'] - df2['bananas'] 


apples  oranges bananas optimal_fruit
1       6       11      -5
2       7       12      2
3       8       13      11
4       9       14      22
5       10      15      35
```

What is happening if I try to do something like this? And how could I do this in a list comprehension?

```
df2['optimal_fruit'] = [x * y - z for x in df2['apples'] for y in df2['oranges'] for z in df2['bananas']]
```

I get an error of:

ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

As always, thank you all so much for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58567199/memory-efficient-way-for-list-comprehension-of-pandas-dataframe-using-multiple-c/62064720#62064720
 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52607864/pandas-list-comprehension-tuple-from-dataframe/62064822#62064822

But this was the first question, so the possible duplicates are rather the 2 links.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting multiple columns in a Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285613/selecting-multiple-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Essentially your list comprehension statement is a set of 3 nested loops. In code:

```
l = []
for x in df2['apples']:
    for y in df2['oranges']:
        for z in df2['bananas']:
            l.append(x * y - z)
```

The length of your resultant list will be power-of-3 times the length of your DataFrame (5x5x5 = 125). Hence the error. To fix, you need the equivalent of:

```
for x, y, z in zip(df2['apples'], df2['oranges'], df2['bananas']):
    l.extend([x * y - z])
```

In terms of list comprehension:

```
[x * y - z for x, y, z in zip(df2['apples'], df2['oranges'], df2['bananas'])]
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason why your new method doesn't work is because the list comprehension produces data that is longer than the number of indices in your dataframe. A quick fix for that would be something like:

```
[x * y - z for x,y,z in zip(df2['apples'], df2['oranges'], df2['bananas'])]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the values of the row as a list using the `np.array()` function inside your list of comprehension.

The following code solves your problem:

```
df2['optimal_fruit'] = [x[0] * x[1] - x[2] for x in np.array(df2)]
```

It is going to avoid the need of typing each column name in your list of comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to repeat df2 for each column:

```
[row[0][0]*row[0][1]-row[0][2] for row in zip(df2[['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas']].to_numpy())]
```

or

```
def func(row):
    print(row[0]*row[1]-row[2])

[func(*row) for row in zip(df2[['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas']].to_numpy())]
```

Further reading:

- [Memory efficient way for list comprehension of pandas dataframe using multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58567199/memory-efficient-way-for-list-comprehension-of-pandas-dataframe-using-multiple-c/62064720#62064720)
- [Dataframe list comprehension "zip(...)": loop through chosen df columns efficiently with just a list of column name strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62064822/11154841)
- [What is the most efficient way to loop through dataframes with pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34311080/11154841)
- [Loop through dataframe one by one (pandas)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59625705/11154841)

EDIT:

Please use `df.iloc` and `df.loc` instead of `df[[...]]`, see [Selecting multiple columns in a Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36955053/11154841)