# Loop through dataframe one by one (pandas)

Tags: python, loops, pandas, dataframe

Let's say we have a dataframe with columns A, B and C:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns =('A','B','C'), index=range(1))
```

The columns holds three rows of numeric values:

```
0     A     B      C
1    2.1   1.8    1.6
2    2.01  1.81   1.58
3    1.9   1.84   1.52
```

How does one loop through every row from 1 to 3 and then execute an if statement including add some variables:

```
if B1 > 1.5
    calc_temp   = A1*10
    calc_temp01 = C1*-10
if B2 > 1.5 
    calc_temp   = A2*10
    calc_temp01 = C2*-10
if B3 >1.5
    calc_temp   = A3*10
    calc_temp01 = C3*-10
```

Is above even possible? It has to know a range of some sorts i.e. full range dataset number with some kind of counter, yes? The if statement should refer to that specific row.

Comment: You can use `for row in df.iterrows():`

Comment: Since you are replacing the already calculated values of `calc_temp` and `calc_temp01`, wouldn't the final values of `calc_temp` and `calc_temp01` be dependent on the values of `A` and `C` corresponding to the last occurrence of B greater than `1.5`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the most efficient way to loop through dataframes with pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837722/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-loop-through-dataframes-with-pandas)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you need [`iterrows`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html):

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['B'] > 1.5:
        calc_temp   = row['A'] *10
        calc_temp01 = row['C'] *-10
```

Comment: If you're accessing the row in a loop, why call `.loc` again?  May as well use `for i in  range(len(df)):`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - sometimes overcomplicated it, thank you for succestion.

Comment: @jezrael - Splendid, it worked. What if we were to plot calc_temp through the iteration while the plot keeps updating. How would one achieve that?

Comment: @Bondeaux - Hard question, if need plotting. Maybe the best is create new question with sample data, desired output and what you try. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

## How to iterate efficiently

If you really have to iterate a Pandas dataframe, you will probably want to **avoid using iterrows()**. There are different methods and the usual `iterrows()` is far from being the best. **itertuples() can be 100 times faster.**

**In short:**

- As a general rule, use `df.itertuples(name=None)`. In particular, when you have a fixed number columns and less than 255 columns. *See point (3)*
- Otherwise, use `df.itertuples()` except if your columns have special characters such as spaces or '-'. *See point (2)*
- It is possible to use `itertuples()` even if your dataframe has strange columns by using the last example. *See point (4)*
- Only use `iterrows()` if you cannot the previous solutions. *See point (1)*

## Different methods to iterate over rows in a Pandas dataframe:

Generate a random dataframe with a million rows and 4 columns:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(1000000, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
    print(df)
```

1) The usual `iterrows()` is convenient, but damn slow:

```
start_time = time.clock()
result = 0
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    result += max(row['B'], row['C'])

total_elapsed_time = round(time.clock() - start_time, 2)
print("1. Iterrows done in {} seconds, result = {}".format(total_elapsed_time, result))
```

2) The default `itertuples()` is already much faster, but it doesn't work with column names such as `My Col-Name is very Strange` (you should avoid this method if your columns are repeated or if a column name cannot be simply converted to a Python variable name).:

```
start_time = time.clock()
result = 0
for row in df.itertuples(index=False):
    result += max(row.B, row.C)

total_elapsed_time = round(time.clock() - start_time, 2)
print("2. Named Itertuples done in {} seconds, result = {}".format(total_elapsed_time, result))
```

3) The default `itertuples()` using name=None is even faster but not really convenient as you have to define a variable per column.

```
start_time = time.clock()
result = 0
for(_, col1, col2, col3, col4) in df.itertuples(name=None):
    result += max(col2, col3)

total_elapsed_time = round(time.clock() - start_time, 2)
print("3. Itertuples done in {} seconds, result = {}".format(total_elapsed_time, result))
```

4) Finally, the named `itertuples()` is slower than the previous point, but you do not have to define a variable per column and it works with column names such as `My Col-Name is very Strange`.

```
start_time = time.clock()
result = 0
for row in df.itertuples(index=False):
    result += max(row[df.columns.get_loc('B')], row[df.columns.get_loc('C')])

total_elapsed_time = round(time.clock() - start_time, 2)
print("4. Polyvalent Itertuples working even with special characters in the column name done in {} seconds, result = {}".format(total_elapsed_time, result))
```

Output:

```
         A   B   C   D
0       41  63  42  23
1       54   9  24  65
2       15  34  10   9
3       39  94  82  97
4        4  88  79  54
...     ..  ..  ..  ..
999995  48  27   4  25
999996  16  51  34  28
999997   1  39  61  14
999998  66  51  27  70
999999  51  53  47  99

[1000000 rows x 4 columns]

1. Iterrows done in 104.96 seconds, result = 66151519
2. Named Itertuples done in 1.26 seconds, result = 66151519
3. Itertuples done in 0.94 seconds, result = 66151519
4. Polyvalent Itertuples working even with special characters in the column name done in 2.94 seconds, result = 66151519
```

[This article is a very interesting comparison between iterrows and itertuples](https://medium.com/swlh/why-pandas-itertuples-is-faster-than-iterrows-and-how-to-make-it-even-faster-bc50c0edd30d)

Comment: Even three times faster again than itertuples is `for r in zip(*t.to_dict("list").values()):`, see [What is the most efficient way to loop through dataframes with pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34311080/11154841).