# Dataframe list comprehension "zip(...)": loop through chosen df columns efficiently with just a list of column name strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, zip, list-comprehension

This is just a nitpicking syntactic question...

I have a dataframe, and I want to use list comprehension to evaluate a function using lots of columns.

I know I can do this

```
df['result_col'] = [some_func(*var) for var in zip(df['col_1'], df['col_2'],... ,df['col_n'])]
```

I would like to do something like this

```
df['result_col'] = [some_func(*var) for var in zip(df[['col_1', 'col_2',... ,'col_n']])]
```

i.e. not having to write `df`  `n` times. I cannot for the life of me figure out the syntax.

Comment: try this `df['result_col'] = [some_func(*var) for var in zip(*df[col for col in ['col_1', 'col_2',... ,'col_n']])]`?

Comment: Why dont you just use apply: `df['reult_col'] = df.apply(lambda x: some_func(*tuple(x.values)), axis=1)` ?

Comment: @cryptonome seems to be a syntax error somewhere.. missing a bracket or paranthesis?

Comment: @gyx-hh i thought apply was slow. But honestly I didnt even consider it

Comment: @cryptonome `df['result_col'] = [some_func(*var) for var in zip(*[df[col] for col in ['col_1', 'col_2',... ,'col_n']])]` worked. thanks. If you want credit for your answer, post it and I'll tag it as the answer.

Comment: @mortysporty perhaps, i didn't try to check the amount of brackets/parens in it. alright then, i'll post an answer, and check the typo first :)

Comment: @mortysporty when you apply you're just looping through the dataframe just like what you're doing with list comprehension .

Comment: Possible duplicate of
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40646458/list-comprehension-in-pandas/62062095#62062095 and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58567199/memory-efficient-way-for-list-comprehension-of-pandas-dataframe-using-multiple-c/62064720#62064720 (though the latter link is younger, so only now it has become a possible duplicate)

Comment: @gyx-hh df.apply(), df.itertuples(), df.iteritems(), df.iterrows() are much slower than list comprehension, not recommended, your comment is wrong, apply and list comprehension are not at all equal in speed

Comment: Thanks for that @Lorenz, was not aware of that - i'm aware df.apply and those methods are slow in general because we are looping, and you should always try to find a different approach that is vectorised - but was not aware list comprehension is faster than df.apply

Comment: Does this answer your question? [list comprehension in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40646458/list-comprehension-in-pandas)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should work, but honestly, OP figured it himself as well, so +1 OP :)

```
df['result_col'] = [some_func(*var) for var in zip(*[df[col] for col in ['col_1', 'col_2',... ,'col_n']])]
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments above, you should use `apply` instead:

```
df['reult_col'] = df.apply(lambda x: some_func(*tuple(x.values)), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks. Im not going through all of the columns in the dataframe tough.. otherwise this would be cleaner, no doubt.

Comment: you can do `df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].apply(...)`

Comment: df.apply(), df.itertuples(), df.iteritems(), df.iterrows() are much slower than list comprehension, not recommended

Answer (score 2):

df.apply() is almost as slow as df.iterrows(), both are not recommended, see [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas) --> search for "An Obvious Example" of @cs95a and see the comparison graph. As the fastest ways (vectorization, Cython routines) are not easy to implement, the 3rd best and thus usually best solution is list comprehension:

```
# print 3rd col
def some_func(row):
    print(row[2])


df['result_col'] = [some_func(*row) for row in zip(df[['col_1', 'col_2',... ,'col_n']].to_numpy())]
```

or

```
# print 3rd col
def some_func(row):
    print(row[2])

df['result_col'] = [some_func(row[0]) for row in zip(df[['col_1', 'col_2',... ,'col_n']].to_numpy())]
```

or

```
# print 3rd col
def some_func(x):
    print(x)

df['result_col'] = [some_func(row[0][2]) for row in zip(df[['col_1', 'col_2',... ,'col_n']].to_numpy())]
```

Further reading:

- [Memory efficient way for list comprehension of pandas dataframe using multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58567199/memory-efficient-way-for-list-comprehension-of-pandas-dataframe-using-multiple-c/62064720#62064720)
- [list comprehension in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62062095/11154841)
- [What is the most efficient way to loop through dataframes with pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34311080/11154841)
- [Loop through dataframe one by one (pandas)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59625705/11154841)

EDIT:

Please use `df.iloc` and `df.loc` instead of `df[[...]]`, see [Selecting multiple columns in a Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36955053/11154841)