# Python Speeding Up a Loop for text comparisons

Tags: python, loops, fuzzywuzzy

I have a loop which is comparing street addresses.
It then uses fuzzy matching to tokenise the addresses and compare the addresses. I have tried this both with `fuzzywuzzy` and `rapidfuzz`.
It subsequently returns how close the match is.
The aim is to try and take all my street addresses 30k or so and match a variation of the street address to a structured street address in my dataset.
The end result would be a reference table with two columns:

- Column A is the reference column address
- Column B is an address where the match is good enough to be associated with column A
- Column A can have many associated addresses.

I am not a huge python user but do know that for loops are the last resort for most problems ([third answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45670242/loop-through-dataframe-one-by-one-pandas)). With that in mind, I have used for loops. However my loops will take approx 235 hours which is sub-optimal to say the least. I have created a reproducible example below. Can anyone see where i can make any tweaks? I have added a progress bar to give you an idea of the speed. You can increase the number of addresses by changing the line `for _ in range(20):`

```
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
from faker import Faker
from rapidfuzz import process, fuzz

# GENERATE FAKE ADDRESSES FOR THE REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE -----------------------------------------------
fake = Faker()
fake_addresses = pd.DataFrame()

for _ in range(20):
    # Generate fake address
    d = {'add':fake.address()}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data = [d])

    # Append it to the addresses dataframe
    fake_addresses = pd.concat([fake_addresses, df])

fake_addresses = fake_addresses.reset_index(drop=True)

# COMPARE ADDRESSES ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
# Here we are making a "dictionary" of the addresses where we use left side as a reference address
# We use the right side as all the different variations of the address. The addresses have to be 
# 0% similar. Normally this is 95% similarity    
reference = fake_addresses['add'].drop_duplicates()
ref_addresses = pd.DataFrame()

# This takes a long time. I have added tqdm to show how long when the number of addresses is increased dramatically
for address in tqdm(reference):
    for raw_address in reference:
        result = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(address, raw_address)
        
        d = {'reference_address': address, 
             'matched_address': raw_address,
             'matched_result': result}
        
        df = pd.DataFrame(data = [d])
        
        if len(df.index) > 0:
            filt = df['matched_result'] >= 0
            df = df.loc[filt]
            ref_addresses = pd.concat([ref_addresses, df], ignore_index=True)
        else:
            ref_addresses = ref_addresses
```

Comment: is the use of pandas a requirement?

Comment: Hi @JonSG, Not at all. I can always convert it back to a Pandas dataframe after the table is finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by pre-calculating the sorted tokens once for each address so that you don't end up doing it n*n-1 times. This allows you to bypass the processor and avoid calling the sort method of the fuzzer. After that, I would take pandas out of the picture at least while doing these tests.

This test runs through 1k faked address in about 2 seconds and 10k in about 4 1/2 minutes. At the moment if addr1 and addr2 are similar we record that both ways.:

```py
import faker
import rapidfuzz
import itertools
import tqdm

## -----------------------
## Generate some "fake" addresses
## apply the deault process once to each address
## sort the tokens once for each address
## -----------------------
faked_address_count = 1_000
make_fake = faker.Faker()
fake_addresses = [make_fake.address() for _ in range(faked_address_count)]
fake_addresses = {
    address: " ".join(sorted(
        x.strip()
        for x
        in rapidfuzz.utils.default_process(address).split(" ")
        if x.strip()
    ))
    for address
    in fake_addresses
}
## -----------------------

## -----------------------
## Find similar addresses
## -----------------------
threshhold = 82
results = {}
pairs = itertools.combinations(fake_addresses.items(), 2)
for (addr1, processed_addr1), (addr2, processed_addr2) in tqdm.tqdm(pairs):
    similarity = rapidfuzz.fuzz.token_ratio(
        processed_addr1,
        processed_addr2,
        processor=None
    )

    if similarity > threshhold:
        results.setdefault(addr1, []).append([addr2, similarity])
        results.setdefault(addr2, []).append([addr1, similarity])  # also record 2 similar to 1?
## -----------------------

## -----------------------
## Print the final results
## -----------------------
import json
print(json.dumps(results, indent=4))
## -----------------------
```

generating a result like:

```
{
    "PSC 0586, Box 8976\nAPO AE 52923": [
        ["PSC 0586, Box 6535\nAPO AE 76148", 83.33333333333334]
    ],
    "PSC 0586, Box 6535\nAPO AE 76148": [
        ["PSC 0586, Box 8976\nAPO AE 52923", 83.33333333333334]
    ],
    "USNS Brown\nFPO AE 20210": [
        ["USNV Brown\nFPO AE 70242", 82.6086956521739]
    ],
    "USNV Brown\nFPO AE 70242": [
        ["USNS Brown\nFPO AE 20210", 82.6086956521739]
    ]
}
```

To create a version that more directly aligns with what I think your inputs and outputs might be, you can take a look at. This will compare 1k standard addresses to 10k test addresses in about 40 seconds.:

```py
import faker
import rapidfuzz
import itertools
import tqdm

## -----------------------
## Generate sets of standard addresses and test addresses
## -----------------------
make_fake = faker.Faker()
standard_addresses = [make_fake.address() for _ in range(1_000)]
test_addresses = [make_fake.address() for _ in range(2_000)]
## -----------------------

## -----------------------
## pre-process the addresses
## -----------------------
def address_normalizer(address):
    return " ".join(sorted(
        x.strip()
        for x
        in rapidfuzz.utils.default_process(address).split(" ")
        if x.strip()
    ))
standard_addresses = {address: address_normalizer(address) for address in standard_addresses}
test_addresses = {address: address_normalizer(address) for address in test_addresses}
## -----------------------

## -----------------------
## Create a list to hold our results
## -----------------------
results = []
## -----------------------

## -----------------------
## Find similar addresses
## -----------------------
threshhold = 82
pairs = itertools.product(standard_addresses.items(), test_addresses.items())
for standard_address_kvp, test_address_kvp in tqdm.tqdm(pairs):
    similarity = rapidfuzz.fuzz.token_ratio(
        standard_address_kvp[1],
        test_address_kvp[1],
        processor=None
    )

    if similarity > threshhold:
        results.append([standard_address_kvp[0], test_address_kvp[0]])
## -----------------------

for pair in results:
    print(pair)
```

That will generate a result like:

```
['USS Collins\nFPO AE 04706', 'USNS Collins\nFPO AE 40687']
['USS Miller\nFPO AP 15314', 'USS Miller\nFPO AP 91203']
['Unit 4807 Box 9762\nDPO AP 67543', 'Unit 6542 Box 9721\nDPO AP 48806']
['Unit 4807 Box 9762\nDPO AP 67543', 'Unit 9692 Box 6420\nDPO AP 46850']
```

Comment: Hi @JonSG, This is really amazing work. So the slowdown is basically because I was sorting the data at each iteration using `fuzz.token_sort_ratio` and using pandas in my loop from what I can see

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
result = pd.DataFrame()
for pos in range(len(reference) - 1):
    comparison = process.extract(reference[pos], reference.iloc[pos+1:], scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio, score_cutoff=1)
    # By setting score_cutoff=1, we only get the matches that have a score of 1 or higher, you can change it to
    # whatever value you want.
    result = pd.concat([result, pd.DataFrame(comparison, columns=['add', 'score', 'pos'])])
    # The pos column is the position of the match in the reference list.

result.drop('pos', axis=1, inplace=True)
# We don't need the pos column, so we drop it.
```

If you have the addresses in two different columns instead you cand do something like the following.

```
result = pd.DataFrame()
for address in fake_addresses_df.add1:
    comparisons = process.extract(address, fake_addresses_df.add2, scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio, score_cutoff=1)
    # By setting score_cutoff=1, we only get the matches that have a score of 1 or higher, you can change it to
    # whatever value you want.
    result = pd.concat([result, pd.DataFrame(comparisons, columns=['add', 'score', 'pos'])])
    # The pos column is the position of the match in the reference list.


result.drop('pos', axis=1, inplace=True)
# We don't need the pos column, so we drop it.
```

It still has room for improvement, but it is much faster than your implementation and the code is simpler.

Also, I would suggest to generate the data with list comprehensions, that are faster and cleaner than regular for loops.

```
fake_addresses = [fake.address() for _ in range(1000)]
fake_addresses2 = [fake.address() for _ in range(1000)]
fake_addresses_df = pd.DataFrame({'add1': fake_addresses, 'add2': fake_addresses2})
# In case you want to create 2 variables
```

Comment: Thank you @JustAnotherWorker. This is much faster than my implementation. I have accepted the answer below because it seems to be faster again. I have learned a lot from your code especially around the list comprehensions

Answer (score 0):

**2nd EDIT**: *This approach is bunk it turns out*, I tried a query of one address against a million and it doesn't finish even one.

==========================

You could try hnswlib maybe. That does nearest neighbor search instead of iterating over the whole thing.

```
import numpy as np
import hnswlib
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

# Function to create an HNSW index for a given list of strings
def create_index(strings):
    # Initialize a CountVectorizer
    vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer="char", ngram_range=(1, 1), lowercase=False)
    
    # Transform the strings into vectors using the vectorizer
    string_vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(strings).toarray()

    # Initialize an HNSW index with cosine similarity and the dimensionality of the string_vectors
    index = hnswlib.Index(space="cosine", dim=string_vectors.shape[1])
    
    # Initialize the HNSW index with the number of strings, construction time search speed (ef_construction), and arity (M)
    index.init_index(max_elements=len(strings), ef_construction=100, M=16)
    
    # Add the string_vectors to the index
    index.add_items(string_vectors)
    
    # Set the search speed at query time (ef)
    index.set_ef(50)

    # Return the index and the vectorizer for future use
    return index, vectorizer

# Function to compute the cosine distances between a query string and a list of strings
def string_distances(query, strings, index, number_of_nearest_neighbors, vectorizer):
    # Transform the query string into a vector using the vectorizer
    query_vector = vectorizer.transform([query]).toarray()
    
    # Perform a k-nearest neighbors search using the HNSW index, where k is the number of strings
    _, distances = index.knn_query(query_vector, k=number_of_nearest_neighbors)
    
    # Convert cosine similarities to cosine distances (1 - similarity)
    return 1 - distances[0]

# Sample list of strings
strings = ["sitting", "cat", "dog", "mittens"]
query = "kitten"

# Create the HNSW index and vectorizer using the list of strings
index, vectorizer = create_index(strings)

# How many near strings do you need?
number_of_nearest_neighbors = 4

# Compute the distances between the query string and the list of strings
distances = string_distances(query, strings, index, number_of_nearest_neighbors, vectorizer)

# reverse distances and strings for proper order
distances = distances[::-1]
strings = strings[::-1]

print("input\t\tdistance\n=========================")
# Print the distances
for distance, string in zip(distances, strings):
    print(f"{string}\t\t{distance}")
```

Edit: Admittedly, I think these results are a little strange, because the top-two nearest are "mittens" and "dog", not "mittens" and "sitting". I'm hoping that it will suit your purpose a little better since addresses are a little longer.