# iterate over pandas dataframe using itertuples

Tags: python, pandas

I am iterating over a pandas dataframe using itertuples. I also want to capture the row number while iterating:

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    print row['name']
```

Expected output :

```
1 larry
2 barry
3 michael
```

1, 2, 3 are row numbers. I want to avoid using a counter and getting the row number. Is there an easy way to achieve this using pandas?

Comment: Refusing to use `enumerate` - a common pattern in Python for these cases - seems weird. I would use it. Otherwise `df.reset_index()` will bring a 0 based index so the row number will be the index you iterate for a given line +1

Comment: You should use `iterrows` like [in this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16476974/1478290)

Comment: @Boud where does it say they refuse to use enumerate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the most efficient way to loop through dataframes with pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837722/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-loop-through-dataframes-with-pandas)

Comment: @Cheng the issue with iterrows is that dtypes may not be consistently maintained across rows.  This can be very problematic.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

When using `itertuples` you get a named `tuple` for every row. By default, you can access the index value for that row with `row.Index`.

If the index value isn't what you were looking for then you can use `enumerate`

```
for i, row in enumerate(df.itertuples(), 1):
    print(i, row.name)
```

`enumerate` takes the place of an ugly counter construct

Comment: Why are counters ugly?

Comment: very ugly for(int i=0; i<= arr.length. ; I++)  instead of enumrate

Answer (score 36):

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    print(getattr(row, 'Index'), getattr(row, 'name'))
```

Comment: Your answer may be correct, but an explanation would help other readers. For more info read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: why getattr? just use `row.Index`, `row.name`

Comment: if the column name is being dynamically synthesized the getattr works nicely as it allows for a string.

Answer (score 13):

For column names that aren't valid Python names, use:

```
for i, row in enumerate(df.itertuples(index=False)):
    print(str(i) + row[df.columns.get_loc('My nasty - column / name')])
```

If you don't specify `index=False`, the column before the one named will be read.

Comment: Any reason for the downvotes? Not bothered, just curious. Have added enumerate, in case that's it.

Comment: I don't think named tuples permit string accessors.

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing your point John, but this is working code that successfully solved my issue. `get_loc` returns the index of the column, not a string.

Comment: You’re right, I must have copied it wrong. Thanks for the clarification!