# Pandas - Looping through multiple items in a Dataframe to a SQL query

Tags: sql, pandas

I have a Dataframe that has two columns, one that mentions the product_name and other that has a key related to that product as shown below:

```
product,key
prod_a, key_1
prod_b, key_2
prod_c, key_3
```

I am trying to query a table such that I apply both the product and its corresponding key in where clause as shown below:

query:

```
cursor.execute("""select prod_name, quantity from table where prod_name = {product} and prod_key = {key}""")
```

`product` and `key` values are taken from the above Dataframe

I would like to loop through each product and key from the above DataFrame into the SQL query ad get the output

Comment: y dont u pass the products  and keys to ```cursor.execute``` as a list and use ```where prod_name IN [list_items]``` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`itertuples()` is faster way to do it.

```
for index, row in df.itertuples():
    cursor.execute("""select prod_name, quantity from table where prod_name = '{row["product"]}' and prod_key = '{row["key"]}'""")
```

> `.itertuples()` yields a namedtuple for each row, with the row’s index
>   value as the first element of the tuple.
>
> `.iterrows()` yields pairs (tuples) of (index, Series) for each row in
>   the DataFrame.

You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43221208/iterate-over-pandas-dataframe-using-itertuples).

Answer (score 1):

Figured using the below:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(index, row["product"],row["key"])

    cursor.execute(f"""select prod_name, quantity from table where prod_name = '{row["product"]}' and prod_key = '{row["key"]}'""")
```