# Loop through rows of pandas dataframe and create variables based on columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` with `df.columns = ['jobID', 'emailAddress', 'jobTitle', 'jobSource', 'contactName']` and `index_col = 'jobID'`

My objective is to loop through each row of this dataframe and create variables based on the value of each 'cell' (intersection of column and row) and pass that to a function I wrote that automates email generation and sending.

This is what I have so far, but this doesn't get it done.

```
for row in df.index():
    email = str(df['emailAddress'])
    jobTitle = str(df['jobTitle'])
    jobSource = str(df['jobSource'])
    jobID = str(df['jobID'])
    nameOfContact = str(df['contactName'])

    """ generate the email subject using string methods
    'This is a subject about %s' % (jobTitle)
    """
    subj = emailSubj(jobSource = jobSource,
              jobTitle = jobTitle,
              jobID = jobID)

    """
    create email body using similar logic as subject
    """
    body = create_emailBody(nameOfContact = nameOfContact)
    """
    Generate and send the email by passing email address, subject, body
    """
    emailTool(email = email,
              subj = subj,
              body = body)
```

This script does run, but I don't think I am properly looping through the rows and naming the variables. I am receiving the entire column instead of the cell.

Comment: Have you tried [pandas apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)?

Comment: Check this link -- > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837722/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-loop-through-dataframes-with-pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `.apply(..., axis=1)`:

```
df.apply(lambda r: 
            emailTool(email=r['emailAddress'],
                      subj=emailSubj(jobSource=r['jobSource'],
                                     jobTitle=r['jobTitle'],
                                     jobID=r['jobID']),
                      body=create_emailBody(nameOfContact=r['contactName'])
            ),
         axis=1
)
```