# Pandas: column present in one df and not in the other

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames A and B with columns, [a,b,c] and [c,d,f] respectively. I want to select the column 'a' from data-frame A, such that the elements of column 'c' are present in A, but not in B. How would I got about it?

Something like the sql equivalent of, 'Select a from A such that c in A and c not in B'

Thanks!

Comment: You should post the data frames along with an example of the desired output. (You will have to do it manually)

Comment: have you tried iterating thru rows and comparing using basic python operations, as described in this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837722/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-loop-through-dataframes-with-pandas

Comment: @cptwonton, I would like to avoid iterating through due to the slow performance.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you are looking for:

```
 A_filtered = A.loc[~A['c'].isin(set(B['c'])), 'a']
```

The `pandas` [Indexing and Selecting Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) documentation has more detail on the syntax.