# Groupby function for cumsum and reset it index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cumsum

I have simple condition:

***if sum for the month // 100:***

> print sum and reset cumsum index

***else:***

> keep cumsumming

Here is my data:

```
data = dict(
    Year=['2018', '2018', '2018', '2018', '2018', '2017', '2017', '2017'],
    Month=['08', '08', '04', '05', '05', '06', '02', '01'],
    Money=[26, 50, 25, 45, 20, 36, 84, 24]
)
```

and here is my attempts:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.groupby(['Year', 'Month']).sum()
df['cum_y'] = df.groupby(['Year']).Money.cumsum() 


df['cum_m'] = df.groupby([lambda x: x // 100], level=0).Money.cumsum()

df['cum_m'] = df.groupby(lambda x: [x if x // 100 else None]).Money.cumsum()

df['cum_m'] = df.groupby(['Money']).agg(lambda x: x // 100).cumsum()
```

and I want something like that:

```
            Money  cum_y  cum_m (Payout actually)
Year Month
2017 01        24    24     x    (means None)
     02        84   108    108 - reset cumsum counter()
     06        36   144     x    (36)
2018 04        25    25     x    (61)
     05        65    90    126 - reset cumsum counter()
     08        76   166     x    (76)
```

Comment: @jezrael updated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that iterating should be avoided whenever possible,  but here is a solution using iteration:

```
total = 0
Cumsum = []
for item in df.Money:
    total += item
    if total < 100:
        Cumsum.append(np.nan)
    else:
        Cumsum.append(total)
        total = 0

df['Cumsum'] = Cumsum
```

Output:

```
               Money    Cumsum
Year    Month       
2017    01     24       NaN
        02     84       108.0
        06     36       NaN
2018    04     25       NaN
        05     65       126.0
        08     76       NaN
```

Comment: So good old plain python is only solution? I was thinking about more panda'nish workaround, meh ~_~ but anyway thank you!

Comment: According to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837722/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-loop-through-dataframes-with-pandas) *(4th answer)* - plain loop in DataFrame element is more efficient **(in 214 times lol)** than dedicated function for iterations like *iterrows* and even *itertuples*! So I definitely steak with your solution, thanks again! =)