# How to pass a list variable to a matplotlib plt.savefig argument

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a for loop that saves a plot at each cycle. I would like the string name of my list, to be the savefig filename. However, Savefig requires a filename path or filename + format.

I am struggling to pass my listed variable string as a filename. Savefig infers the dataframe itself instead of the string name. Suggestions to overcome much appreciated.

Ultimately i would like my graphs to be named apples and bananas (See below).

I have tried below methods within my for loop however all returned error.

```
#plt.savefig(str(item))
#plt.savefig("Graph" + str(item) +".png", format="PNG")
#plt.savefig('Graph_{}.png'.format(item))   
#plt.savefig(item, format='.jpg')

apples = df_final[(df_final['Timetag [UTC]'] > '21/12/2018  13:28:00') & 
(df_final['Timetag [UTC]'] <= '21/12/2018  19:00:00')]

bananas = df_final[(df_final['Timetag [UTC]'] > '21/12/2018  17:28:00') & 
(df_final['Timetag [UTC]'] <= '21/12/2018  21:00:00')]


List_to_plot = [apples, bananas]


for item in List_to_plot:
    item.plot(y='Delta Port/STBD', label='Sway')
    plt.savefig(str(item))
    plt.show()
    plt.clf()
```

> File "", line 17, in 
>       plt.savefig(str(item))
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py",
>   line 689, in savefig
>       res = fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py",
>   line 2094, in savefig
>       self.canvas.print_figure(fname, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py",
>   line 2006, in print_figure
>       canvas = self._get_output_canvas(format)
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py",
>   line 1948, in _get_output_canvas
>       .format(fmt, ", ".join(sorted(self.get_supported_filetypes()))))
>
> ValueError: Format '027619\n\n[19920 rows x 15 columns]' is not
>   supported (supported formats: eps, jpeg, jpg, pdf, pgf, png, ps, raw,
>   rgba, svg, svgz, tif, tiff)

Comment: Replace `plt.savefig(str(item))` by `plt.savefig(str(item) + '.jpg')` for example. The problem is due to saving the images with unknown extensions

Comment: I have tried this previously however the savefig reads my item as the dataframe and not the string of the variable (apples, bananas).

Comment: What do you get as a return after you tried it?

Comment: File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1966, in save
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "w+b")

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '              Timetag [UTC]  UTMposMeasN1 []     ...      pitch1 [°]  heave1 [m]\n6892822 2018-12-21 13:28:01      10014875.49

Comment: ^ the savefig is trying to save using my dataframe itself and not the name of the variable which is what i would like (apples bananas)

Comment: Then, you should loop over the dataframes you have (apples and bananas) to get the filenames from them then save your images. Useful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837722/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-loop-through-dataframes-with-pandas)

Comment: Not sure that looping through my filenames would correlate correctly with my dataframes. Unless you have a loop in mind. Is there a way i can directly infer the list index string name?

Comment: I edited my answer (2nd time), please try what I suggested and tell me about the results.

Answer (score 1):

According to the error you got, the problem is due to saving the images with unknown extensions.
So the problem can be fixed by simply adding an extension ('jpg', 'png', ...) to `plt.savefig(str(item))`, to be `plt.savefig(str(item) + '.jpg')`.

**EDIT:**
Since the `list_to_plot` contains dataframes and based to what we discussed on the comment, I suggest the following:
Create another list with the dataframes names, then the solution would be as following:

```
List_to_plot = [apples, bananas]
names = ['apples', 'bananas']
# loop over the element in the list_to_plot
for elt in (0, 1):
    # loop over the length of each dataframe to get the index of the image
    for i in range(list_to_plot[elt].shape[0]):
        # do your processing
        item.plot(y='Delta Port/STBD', label='Sway')
        # save the image with the appropriate index
        plt.savefig(names[elt] + '{}.jpg'.format(i))
        plt.show()
        plt.clf()
```