# Pandas Dataframes: is the value of a column in a list nested in another column, same row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I am working with a Pandas dataframe similar to with:

```
     My_date      Something_else    My_list
0    25/10/2019   ...               [25/10/2019, 26/10/2019]
1    03/07/2019   ...               [28/11/2017, 12/12/2017, 26/12/2017]
2    09/04/2019   ...               [11/06/2015]
```

I would like to check if the value in the column called "*My_date*" is in the list on the same row, column "*My_list*". For instance here I would like to get the following output, **vectorially** or **very efficiently**:

```
     Result
0    true
1    false
2    false
```

I could do this using a '*for*' loop, various methods are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837722/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-loop-through-dataframes-with-pandas) for instance. However, I am aware that iterating is [rarely the best solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/12236313), all the more since my table has more than 1 million rows and many of the list have 365 values. (But as shown above, these lists are not always *date ranges*.)

I know that there are many ways to do vectorial calculation on DataFrames, using .*loc* or .*eval* for instance. The point is that in my case, nothing works as expected due to these nested lists... Thus, I would like to **find a vectorized solution** to do that. If it matters, all my "*dates*" are of type `pandas.Timestamp`.

There are probably other questions related to similar issues, however I haven't found any appropriate answer or question using my own words.

Comment: The easiest solution would be to use apply here as the lists are raising a dimension issue when processing things column based

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
df['Result'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['My_date'] in x['My_list'], axis=1)
```

---

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'My_date' : ['25/10/2019','03/07/2019','09/04/2019'], 'My_list' : [['25/10/2019', '26/10/2019'],['28/11/2017', '12/12/2017', '26/12/2017'],['11/06/2015']]})
df['Result'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['My_date'] in x['My_list'], axis=1)
```

Outputs:

```
      My_date                               My_list  Result
0  25/10/2019              [25/10/2019, 26/10/2019]   True
1  03/07/2019  [28/11/2017, 12/12/2017, 26/12/2017]  False
2  09/04/2019                          [11/06/2015]  False
```