# How to vectorize a function that uses both row and column elements of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I have two inputs in a dataframe, and I need to create an output that depends on both inputs (same row, different columns), but also on its previous value (same column, previous row).

This dataframe command will create an example of what I need:

`df=pd.DataFrame([[0,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,0], [1,1,1], [0,1,1], [0,1,1], [0,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,1,0], [1,1,1], [1,1,1], [0,1,1], [0,1,1], [1,1,1], [0,1,1], [0,1,1], [0,0,0], [0,1,0]], columns=['input_1', 'input_2', 'output'])`

The rules are simple:

- If input_1 is 1, output is 1 (input_1 is a trigger function)
- output will remain as 1 as long as input_2 is also 1. (input_2 works kind of like a memory function)
- For all the others, output will be 0

The rows go in sequence as they happen in time, I mean, row 0 output influences row 1 output, row 1 output influences row 2 output, and so on. So output depends on input_1, input_2, but also on its own previous value.

I could code it looping through the dataframe, computing and assigning values using iloc, but it is painfully slow. I need to run this through many thousands of rows for tens of thousands of dataframes, so I am looking for the most efficient way to do it (preferably vectorization). It can be with numpy or other library/method that you know.

I searched and found some questions about vectorization and row-looping, but I still don't see how to use those techniques. Example questions: [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas). Also this one, [What is the most efficient way to loop through dataframes with pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837722/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-loop-through-dataframes-with-pandas)

I appreciate your help

Comment: Rule number 4 conflicts with the original statement. You say that the output depends on inputs #1 and #2 and on its previous value. In rule #4 you say that the output also depends on the previous value of input #2. Please specify which of the statements is correct.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. In this case, rule #4 is unnecessary. Try to write the conditions in the form of a number of three bits (input #1, input#2, prev. output). Let's translate your rules for the language of numbers. Rule #1: output will be 1 if the input is more than 3 (combinations 100 101 110 111). Rule #2 output will be 1 if the input is 3 (011). Rule #3: output is zero in the remaining cases, that is, if the input number is less than 3 (combinations 000 001 010). Rule #4 says that if the input number is 2 (010), then the output will be 0, but we already know this from rule #3

Comment: Hi @Sergey. You have a point in translating the rules into numbers. However "previous output" belongs to a different row, and that is exactly what I want to overcome in order to vectorize the solution. I don't want to put it in an horizontal rule, because that is not what I have. I will delete rule #4, as it is repeating something already said. Thanks!!!

Comment: Hi @xiaxio, did I understand correctly that you initially only have two columns and zero as the initial output?

Comment: Hi @Sergey. I have 'input_1' and 'input_2' columns. I need to generate the 'output' column. I cannot use it as you did in your answer.

Comment: Hi @xiaxio, I changed the answer based on your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you explained in the discussion above we have just two inputs loaded using pandas dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[0,0], [0,1], [0,0], [1,1], [0,1], [0,1], [0,0], [0,1], [0,1], [1,1], [1,1], [0,1], [0,1], [1,1], [0,1], [0,1], [0,0], [0,1]], columns=['input_1', 'input_2'])
```

We have to create outputs using following rules:

```
#1 if input_1 is one the output is one
#2 if both inputs is zero the output is zero
#3 if input_1 is zero and input_2 is one the output holds the previous value
#4 the initial output value is zero
```

to generate outputs we can

1. duplicate input_1 to the output
2. update output with previous value if input_1 is zero and input_2 is one

because of the rules above we don't need to update the first output

```
df['output'] = df.input_1

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
   if (idx > 0) and (row.input_1 == 0) and (row.input_2 == 1):
       df.output[idx] = df.output[idx-1]

print(df)
```

The output is:

```
>>> print(df)
    input_1  input_2  output
0         0        0       0
1         0        1       0
2         0        0       0
3         1        1       1
4         0        1       1
5         0        1       1
6         0        0       0
7         0        1       0
8         0        1       0
9         1        1       1
10        1        1       1
11        0        1       1
12        0        1       1
13        1        1       1
14        0        1       1
15        0        1       1
16        0        0       0
17        0        1       0
```

**UPDATE1**

The more fast way to do it is modification of formula proposed by @Andrej

```
df['output_2'] = (df['input_1'] + df['input_2'] * 2).replace(2, np.nan).ffill().replace(3, 1).astype(int)
```

Without modification his formula creates wrong output for input combination [1, 0]. It holds the previous output instead of setting it to 1.

**UPDATE2**

This just to compare results

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[0,0], [1,0], [0,1], [1,1], [0,1], [0,1], [0,0], [0,1], [0,1], [1,1], [1,1], [0,1], [0,1], [1,1], [0,1], [0,1], [0,0], [0,1]], columns=['input_1', 'input_2'])

df['output'] = df.input_1
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
   if (idx > 0) and (row.input_1 == 0) and (row.input_2 == 1):
       df.output[idx] = df.output[idx-1]

df['output_1'] = (df['input_1'] + df['input_2'] * 2).replace(2, np.nan).ffill().replace(3, 1).astype(int)
df['output_2'] = (df['input_1'] + df['input_2']).replace(1, np.nan).ffill().replace(2, 1).astype(int)
print(df)
```

The results is:

```
>>> print(df)
    input_1  input_2  output  output_1  output_2
0         0        0       0         0         0
1         1        0       1         1         0
2         0        1       1         1         0
3         1        1       1         1         1
4         0        1       1         1         1
5         0        1       1         1         1
6         0        0       0         0         0
7         0        1       0         0         0
8         0        1       0         0         0
9         1        1       1         1         1
10        1        1       1         1         1
11        0        1       1         1         1
12        0        1       1         1         1
13        1        1       1         1         1
14        0        1       1         1         1
15        0        1       1         1         1
16        0        0       0         0         0
17        0        1       0         0         0
```

Comment: Thanks Sergey!! Your code creates the right answer. As I said to Andrej, I will measure the times of the solutions. I will give the accepted answer to the fastest one, as I believe this question will be useful for several data-manipulation programmers. I am honored that you really dig into this one.

Comment: The method proposed by @Andrej is faster than my but he uses wrong formula. I will try to update my answer

Comment: Hi @Sergey. Andrej uses some tricks to implement vectorization, which is the recommended technique to obtain the fastest results when doing operations over long dataframes. Even though he is not using a mathematical formula, he is using coding logic to obtain the same result, in a faster way, which is exactly what I am looking for. The links I provided in the question explain this issue (go through the answers in those questions and you will see what I mean)

Comment: Hi @xiaxio. The code proposed by Andrej gives you wrong results if you have [1,0] input combination. It process [1,0] and [0,1] in the same way. But your requirements is to set output to 1 for inputs [1,0] and keep previous output for inputs [0,1]. Please read update1 in my answer

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you right, you want to know how to compute column `output`. You can do for example:

```
df['output_2'] = (df['input_1'] + df['input_2']).replace(1, np.nan).ffill().replace(2, 1).astype(int)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    input_1  input_2  output  output_2
0         0        0       0         0
1         0        1       0         0
2         0        0       0         0
3         1        1       1         1
4         0        1       1         1
5         0        1       1         1
6         0        0       0         0
7         0        1       0         0
8         0        1       0         0
9         1        1       1         1
10        1        1       1         1
11        0        1       1         1
12        0        1       1         1
13        1        1       1         1
14        0        1       1         1
15        0        1       1         1
16        0        0       0         0
17        0        1       0         0
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrej Kesely, this gives me the output in a considerably shorter amount of time. I will wait a couple of days to measure the time between different answers, to choose the fastest one as the right one (assuming I receive more answers). I very much appreciate your answer. And yes, I want to calculate the output column, just as you did :-)