# Creating a list of items from a json file

Tags: python, pandas

i am trying to write a code that filters a json file into two columns using Pandas in python. after the filter has been done, i want to create a loop that would add the items in the column to be added to a list called review

```
import pandas as pd

reviews = []
df = pd.read_json('Books_small.json', lines=True)

data = df[['reviewText', 'overall']]

for b in data:
   reviews.append(b)

print(len(reviews))
```

Comment: Okay, so what happened when you tried that code? How is that different from what you want to happen?

Comment: i just get ['reviewText', 'overall'] as the content of the list; reviews =[] and the length is  two instead should be more than that. the json file has over 500 items in it

Comment: It would be helpful to show sample input file as well as expected output.

Comment: the first 16mins of this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M9Itm95JzL0). he is using json library, but i decided to try to use panda to get the same result

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837722/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-loop-through-dataframes-with-pandas help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest something like that :

If your data frame **"data"** is equal to

```
     reviewText       overall
0   Doesn´t work     MongoDB
1   Very good        Python
```

## CODE

```
reviews = [] 
for i in range(len(data)):
    reviews.append([data.reviewText[i],data.overall[i]])

print(len(reviews))
print('\n')
print(reviews)
```

## Output

```
2


[['Doesn´t work ', 'MongoDB'], ['Very good ', 'Python']]
```

Comment: can i kiss you? Thanks so much