# forloop over 500000 rows python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I have a forloop that is changing the address format of over 500,000 rows, it works but it's taking a long time to run. Is there a way to make it run more efficiently?

```
for lab, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[lab,"Address"] = (row["Address"].title())
```

Comment: With 500K rows using a database would be a far better option. Although title-casing a field won't benefit from indexing.

Comment: `df.Address.str.title()` I'm not sure if this is faster. String methods are usually not vectorized in `pandas`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the most efficient way to loop through dataframes with pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837722/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-loop-through-dataframes-with-pandas)

Comment: @Rivers that doesn't answer the question at all. The answer's code is the same code used here

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The accepted answer says "If you want it faster, use itertuples"

Comment: Benchmarked `pandas` `str.title()` with 100k rows: its ~650x faster. Always meassure.

Answer (score 0):

You never want to use `iterrows()`. Indeed, you will want to stay away from any kind of custom row-wise iterations. Try this instead for your specific purpose.

```
df.assign(Address=lambda d: d["Address"].str.title())
```

It will return the dataframe with the updated column.

Here is the speed test as requested. It is just about 266x faster.

```
%timeit df.assign(Address=lambda d: d["Address"].str.title())
# 100 ms ± 2.62 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit for lab, row in df.iterrows(): df.loc[lab,"Address"] = (row["Address"].title()) 
# 26.6 s ± 2.63 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Since this creates a new df, might that expense negate the benefit of not using `iterrows()`?

Comment: Not at all. It doesn't create a new df but simply adds the new column and returns the original object.

Comment: The documentation says: "Returns a new object with all original columns in addition to new ones"

Comment: I stand corrected. I believe it will still be significantly faster but I wil create an example to test it.

Comment: Thanks academy, df.assign worked but I had to run it as df=df.assign etc to update the DF permanently. It ran in a heartbeat

Comment: No problem. If this answered your question, please consider marking it as the correct answer.